# How do I create this hover button Using HTML, css and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

`

```css
/* Button */

.button {
    margin: 1em 0em;
}
.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #1A718A;
  
  position:relative;
}

.button h3{
  position:relative;
  top:3.4em;
  left:.5em;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400!important;
  font-size:.9em!important;
  z-index: 1;
}



.circle:hover {
    position:relative;
    top:1em;
    left:3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <div class="text"><h3>- View <span>Work</span></h3></div>
  <div class="circle"></div> 
</div> <!--button-->
```

`How do I create this hover button Using HTML, css and javascript.

The circle moves to the right(no effects) whilst the view turns grey and the work turns white(inverse).

Also a code newbie :)

Default State

[image]

Hover state

[image]

Thankyou

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+css+hover+button+transform+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Java or Javascript? These are two different languages.

Comment: What is the hover effect exactly? Does it bounce? Jump? Spin? You need to clarify what you need assistance with

Comment: @jeremythile It's javascript. I updated the title, getting used to stackoverflow as this is my first post. Can you solve this issue or did you just want to raise my typo?

Comment: @sigurdmazanti The circle moves to the right(no effects) whilst the view turns grey and the work turns white(inverse). As this has been updated can you offer the "assistance" ?

Comment: Does "move to the right" mean it immediately appears there, or does it mean it smoothly (linearly, with easing, etc.) transitions to that position?

Answer (score 0):

## Recreation

### HTML

We want to animate an element and its text "- View Work", so the simplest HTML we can have is:

```html
<p>- View Work</p>
```

### Styling

#### Default style

We can then style it as much as necessary. To place the line in the middle, we can trick a little by setting `line-height` to the element's `height` with a bit of JavaScript:

```js
const p = document.querySelector('p');
p.style = '--height:' + getComputedStyle(p).getPropertyValue('height');
```

```css
p {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: black;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  
  width: 14rem;
  height: 10rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: var(--height);
  text-transform: uppercase
}
```

```html
<p>- View Work</p>
```

#### With flashlight-effect

Now we want to add the circle, in which the text's color is different.

We could probably use [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) in some way, however I don't understand it well enough to make it work with it.

Because of that, we fall back to using pseudo-elements (more specifically, `::after`).
The pseudo-element needs to ...:

- ... have the same text in a different color, and have the texts overlap
- ... be big enough to fit the revealing circle in all its positions inside
- ... clip out the rest not inside the revealing circle

The first two bullet points are as simple as styling the pseudo-element and the parent mostly the same way.
To get the text, we can again use JavaScript by setting a custom [data-attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) (e.g. `data-text`) to have the text. The pseudo-element can then display the text with `content: attr(data-text)`.

For the revealing circle, we give the pseudo-element a background-color. Then, we use `clip-path` to cut out what should be "revealed".

And on hover, we transition between two different positions of the revealing circle.

```js
const p = document.querySelector('p');
p.dataset.text = p.innerText;
p.style = '--height:' + getComputedStyle(p).getPropertyValue('height');
```

```css
p {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: black;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

p, p::after {
  width: 14rem;
  height: 10rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: var(--height);
  text-transform: uppercase
}

p::after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: #1A718A;
  clip-path: circle(3rem at 70px 55px);
  transition: clip-path 0.15s;;
  pointer-events: none;
}

p:hover::after {
  clip-path: circle(3rem at 155px 100px);
}
```

```html
<p>- View Work</p>
```

### End note

This sample-code only works for one-liners, and requires the element to have a fixed size.
The effect can also be achieved by using mostly JavaScript, where one could mock-up such
a pseudo-element with actual HTML-elements, and then overlay said element over the original.